# How to create a notification channel group?

Tags: java, android

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String channel_Id = "Daily";
    CharSequence name = "Daily";
    String description = "Get Notifications about today's rupee changes";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channel_Id,name,importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    String group = "Daily_group";
    CharSequence group_name = "Daily Notifications";
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(new NotificationChannelGroup(group,group_name));
    channel.setGroup("Daily_group");
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_Id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!").setGroup("Daily_group");


    notificationManager.notify(123,mBuilder.build());
    Log.d(tag,"Done");
```

I used this code to create a group but, sadly a group is not created can anyone help me with this problem

Comment: are you using a device running android o?

Comment: take a look at this example https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c

Comment: Yes my device in running O

Comment: The example is what I have  done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I do and it works:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

NotificationChannelGroup notificationChannelGroup=
         new  NotificationChannelGroup(GROUP_ID, 
                                 getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.GROUP_NAME));
notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(notificationChannelGroup);
```

More reading on groups can be found here: [channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#java)  and   [Notif. Groups](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannelGroup) and  [Group  of notif.](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group)

Note that there is a difference between Notifications group (Group of Notifications, previously called Bundled notifications) and Notification Channel Group.Confusing ...